# html/haml to sass convertor - in order to bootstrap an initial sass file

Tags: html, css, sass, gruntjs

Across the web I've found several tools regarding html to css convertors (to generate classes). a fine example is this convertor: http://primercss.com/index.php

However, I was wondering (And couldn't find by myself) if there are advanced tools that convert the html to scss - and if there are tools that I can customise the scss on the go (for example - to decide whether to nest a specific class inside another class).

I'm using in my project grunt so if there is a grunt plugin that might generate this sort of thing automatically that can also be good help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read about this grunt plugin:
 https://github.com/htmlhero/grunt-init-block

I use it on my projects and it's a very useful

Comment: thanks for you response. but I'm not looking to automate the process. I'm looking for a good tool that generates sass files in a clever way (and doesn't just throw classes in a nested tree)